# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ contains an ideal $I$ which can be generated by 3 elements, but not by 2 elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals

My first thought was $(2,x,y)$. But as in this post, [Show that any ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ containing $y$ can be generated by $2$ elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513446/show-that-any-ideal-in-mathbbcx-y-containing-y-can-be-generated-by-2), $(2,x,y)$ would be generated by 2 elements. Does anyone know how to prove the statement in general? I am practicing for my qualifying exam next month. I think the problem is designed to be solved without using knowledge from algebraic geometry.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622081/ideal-of-mathbbcx-y-not-generated-by-two-elements

Comment: The ideal $(2,x,y)$ is generated by one element because $(2,x,y)=(1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $I=(X^2,XY,Y^2)\subset \mathbb Q[X,Y]$. Since $I$ is homogeneous, if $f(X,Y)\in I$, the homogeneous components of $f$ also belong to $I$. If $I$ could be generated by $2$ elements, $f_1,f_2\in I$, then $f_i$ has no homogeneous component of degree $0$ or $1$. So the homogeneous elements of degree $2$ in $I$ can be generated by $2$ elements as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. But $\dim_\mathbb Q I\cap \{aX^2+bXY+cY^2 \ : \ a,b,c \in \mathbb Q \}=3$. So we get a contradiction.

Comment: Not sure this adds anything, but it helps me to picture $\Bbb Q[x,y]$ as a graded ring. Then the short version of the story is that, if $f_1,f_2$ generate $I$ over $\Bbb Q[x,y]$, then $f_1$ and $f_2$ generate the grade-$2$ component of $I$ over $\Bbb Q$.